# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Начал изучать Flask. Там сказано что шаблон html хранится в папке temlates на установочном питон3. Нету такого файла. Куда скопировать нужно html файл.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: В папку templates?

Comment: нет такой папке вообще

Comment: Ну так создайте

Comment: Вот) Вопрос был в этом. Где эту папку нужно создавать

Comment: В папке, где вы запускаете свою программу

Comment: Все наконец то! Спасибо!